# Реализовать на вордпресс кнопку поделится из андроид

Tags: wordpress

Возможно-ли реализовать на вордпресс вызов функции "Поделится" в Андроид (смотрите скрин)?  [image: Поделится]

Как это должно выглядеть: под постом или картинкой отображается кнопка "Поделится", при нажатии на кнопку вызывается функция приведенная в скрине.

Comment: Есть navigator.share
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/share

Answer (score 1):

Нет. Это функции не движка, а андроид-приложения с определёнными правами доступа к данным устройства.